# Historical components of the Nikkei 225 index over time (pre-2000)?

Tags: stock-markets, market-indexes

I'm looking for the historic components of the Nikkei 225 index as far back as 1995 in order to determine when different companies were in the index. I know Nikkei offers this data on one of their websites in the form of articles saying when different companies joined or left the index, but it only goes back as far as 8/24/2000.

Between 1995 and 2000, which companies joined and left the index?  How can I find this information?

Comment: Welcome to Money.SE.  I've edited your question in an attempt to keep it from getting closed as off-topic.

Comment: On the plus side, I believe the Nikkei's components change only once per year, so you only need 6 datasets!

Comment: Thanks Ben. On that note, is there a better SE site for this question? Or was it just the way I initially formatted it?

Comment: @DougMacArthur It's a good question, and this is the right site for it. The only problem was that product and service recommendation requests are officially off-topic here, and if you use the keywords "websites" or "products" in your question, it tends to attract close votes.

Answer (score 1):

The information is available, but unlikely to be free.  Often 'index providers' regard this kind of information as proprietary and charge people for the specific details.  As anyone who is seriously trading index-based securities needs this information, they have been able to charge quite a lot for this data (as the serious traders are willing to pay this amount).

It may also be available through market data service providers (resellers) such as Bloomberg Data License, but this starts at $500 per month just for access to the service.

I would contact Nikkei themselves (the Nihon Keizai Shinbun newspaper) for this information (www.nikkei.com).  They may be able to refer you to their authorised resellers if they are not able to provide the data you are requesting directly.